# How many 4-digit numbers $abcd$ such that $a\neq0$ , $|a-b|=2$ and $|b-c|=3$?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many 4-digit numbers **$abcd$** such that $a\neq0$  , $|a-b|=2$   and   $|b-c|=3$ ?

my try:

I list down all possibilities of  $|a-b|=2$  and then choose appropriate values for $c$ so that $|b-c|=3$.

I have found  **$23$** triples $abc$ and the digit $d$ can be any number from $0$ to $9$ so the total number is $23\times10=230$

First , is this solution right?

Second , is there another approach without listing all cases ?

Can anyone provide a code for this problem ?

Comment: Yes it's right. Try this Mathematica code            Length[Select[IntegerDigits[Range[1000, 9999]], 
  Abs[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] == 2 && Abs[#[[2]] - #[[3]]] == 3 &]]

Comment: @Raffaele  thank you very much,  but honestly I haven't  any knowledge dealing with  Mathematica  , I sometimes  see  some members provide solutions using this Mathematica , if you can list the full code with the answer,   I would be very grateful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's effectively counting all possible cases, but doing it a bit smarter. Because $b$ is common to the two selection criteria, go through the 10 values of $b$ and count how many combinations of $a$ and $c$ exist that satisfy the conditions with that $b$. Doing this, we see that for $b=0,1,2$ there is only one $a$ and one $c$ that satisfy the selection rules. For $b=3,4,5,6$ there are two $a$s and two $c$s. For $b=7$ there are two $a$s and one $c$. For $b=8,9$ there is only one $a$ and one $c$. Adding them all up gives $3\times1+4\times4+1\times2+2\times1=23$. Multiply by the 10 values of d, and you've got your answer.

Comment: elegant  solution  , thank you